# Z-Index on Fixed element outside of FullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm trying to create what I think would be a cool content effect, whereby a dark semi-transparent background covers the entire screen while certain content rises above it, thus creating a highlight effect. I'm a massive `JS` amateur but I've been using `fullPage.js` (https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) to create a scrolling content area, and also used a small drop down `jQuery` within the `FullPage`. I set up a function to bring my darkness `div` to the foreground, and it covers the entire screen as I expected, however, the drop down list within the `fullPage` simply won't rise above it, no matter what I try.

CSS of the darkness div:

```
#darkness {
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
display:none;
height:100%;
left:0;
position: fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:10;
}
```

This is my JS function:

```
function thedarkside () {

    console.log ('the dark side');
    $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
}
```

All of that works as intended. However I can't get my drop down `#dd` to have a `z-index` higher than darkness div. This is the general structure of the `FullPage.js`:

```
Darkness -->
<-- Darkness

    Fullpage -->
        Section -->
            Form -->
                Dropdown -->
                <-- Dropdown
            <-- Form
        <-- Section
    <--Fullpage
```

I set the `z-index` of drop down to something ridiculous like 100, as I don't want any of the other elements to be above the darkness div. I really only want `Dropdown`to be above. Anyway if anyone could help me achieve this affect I'd really appreciate it. I'm ok if the solution lies in `JS` as opposed to `CSS`.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Can you create a plank or jsbin or jsfiddle for this? THEN will I be happy to help.

Comment: @PeterAronZentai Sure, only I'm not entirely sure how I'd go about doing that with so many different jQueries, give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It took the JSFiddles for me to discover why it wasn't happening. I had to turn off the `css3` flag on start of the `FullPage.js` and now it works.

Hope this helps anyone else who experiences something similar.

Comment: That's probably because you are not using the latest fullpage.js (2.X) and using a wrapper for your plugin. If you use it, just placing a fixed element outside the wrapper would work normally. Otherwise, using the `fixedElements` option would have solved it as well.

Comment: @Alvaro Hi, I'm using `fullPage v 2.1.5` and I had used `fixedElements` on the `darkness` div.

Comment: I don't know about your divs, I'm just saying to avoid problems with fixed elements you should do exactly the same as provided in this example in fullpage.js: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/fixedHeaders.html  (you can see the sourcecode for it)